# WP7 TextBox to 2 Integers

Tags: windows-phone-7

As you can see in my code below, I am looking to only figure out how to tell whether there has been more than 2 integers into the HouseholdNoTextBox.

```
private void btnContinue1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HouseholdNoTextBox.Text))
        {
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        if (//HouseholdNoTextBox.Text has > than 2 integers input)
        {
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // collapse the first error box if it is visible
            textBlockError2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // and make visible the second
        }
    }
```

Comment: by saying "two integers" will you distinguish 01 and 10? I mean will "01" be treated as "two integers"?

Comment: I am not bothered what 2 integers they put, as long as they are not able to go over the 2 integer mark

Comment: i believe there is issues when it comes to .Text when checking data in a TextBox and it prefers to work when we ask about its string rather. is there a way to validate whether it is GREATER than 2 against its STRING? e.g. if (string.equals(HouseHoldNoTextBox.Text == 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void btnContinue1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HouseholdNoTextBox.Text))
        {
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
int val;
        if (HouseholdNoTextBox.Text.Length>2 && int.TryParse(HouseholdNoTextBox.Text, out val) && val > 99)
        {
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // collapse the first error box if it is visible
            textBlockError2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // and make visible the second
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this code checking to see if the length of text is GREATER than 2?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final working code. I will +1 Cybermaxs answer as he lead me in the right direction

```
private void btnContinue1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HouseholdNoTextBox.Text))
        {
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;                
        }
        if (HouseholdNoTextBox.Text.Length >= 3)
        {//checking to see if it has a length greater than 2
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // collapse the first error box if it is visible
            textBlockError2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // and make visible the second
        }
        if (HouseholdNoTextBox.Text.Length <= 2 && HouseholdNoTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            textBlockError2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }           
    }
```